# Bias of a variance estimator

Tags: statistics

Let $X_1,X_2,...,X_N$ be i.i.d. r.v. with mean $μ$ and variance $σ^2$. Define the variance estimator $V =(Σ(X_i - \bar{X})^2)/n$ (where $\bar{X}$ is the sample mean). Compute the bias of V.

Expanding the bracket inside the sum gives me the number $-2(E(X_i\bar{X})$. Since $X_i,\bar{X}$ are random variables for every $i$, then so is $X_i\bar{X}$, but how do I compute its expected value? Do I have to check if $X_i, \bar{X}$ are independent for every $i$ ? (I guess they are not, but I wouldn't know how to check it)

Comment: $\newcommand{\Xbar}{\overline{X}}\newcommand{\E}{\mathbb{E}}$Note that $\Xbar = \frac{1}{n}(X_1 + \cdots + X_n)$. Therefore, for each $i$, we have $$\E\left[X_i \Xbar \right] = \frac{1}{n}\E\left[X_i(X_1 + \cdots + X_n) \right].$$ Can you compute this expectation? (To do so, use linearity of expectation, and use the values of $\E\left[X_i^2 \right]$ and $\E\left[X_i X_j \right]$ where $i\ne j$. (Make sure you can compute these expectations first.))

Comment: Yes, I know how to compute this, so I get it now, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome!